# Node JS & Express Json parser

Tags: json, node.js, express

i try to get the username from a json request

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.username);
});
```

The console output:

```
undefined
POST /question 200 39.384 ms - 28
```

This is the Output when i try:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Output:

```
{ '{"user":[{"username":"test"}]}': '' }
```

How can i get the Username?

Comment: Well, the JSON string itself is a _key_ in that object... What is the raw response from the server (without body_parser or whatever)?

Comment: Either your client isn't providing the correct headers, or the server isn't configured to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical for JSON data being posted to Express with an improper content type declaration, namely `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`.

Make sure that the client posting the data is using the latter.